# не обходятся все элементы цикла

Tags: c++, массивы, qt, графы, дерево

```
#пишу функцию, которая должна обойти 100 элементов в одномерном массиве, представленном в виде таблице, переходить к существующему соседу(любому), а далее из нее вызываю функцию, которая будет присваивать этому соседу какое-то число( для начала  всем  5), но обходятся не все 100 элементов#
'''`QVector<int>  bricks;
QVector<bool> visited;
int brrr[100];

void generation(int t){
    brrr[t]=5;
   // bricks[t] = 5;
    visited[t] = true;
}

void randoms(){
    visited.push_back(true);
    for (int v = 1; v < 100; v++)
        visited.push_back(false);

    for (int t = 0; t < 100; t++){
        srand(time(0));
        int ri = t / 10;
        bool neigbour = true;

        int n1 = 10*ri + t +1; //правый
        int n2 = 10*ri + t -1;//левый
        int n3 = t + 10;//нижний
        int n4 = t - 10;//верхний

        //если находимся в первой строчке
        if ( ( n4 < 0) && (t != 0) && (t != 9))
        {
            //рандом для левого, правого и нижнего
            //если существует хоть один свободный сосед, выбираем любого
            if ( (visited[n1] == false) || (visited[n2] == false) || (visited[n3] == false))
            {
                int arr1[3] = {n2,n1,n3};
                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr1[rand()%3];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }

                if ( neigbour == false){
                    //переход к формированию конфигов
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }

        //если находимся в первом столбце
        if ((t%10 == 0) && (t!= 0) && (t != 90))
        {
            //верхнего, правого, нижнего
            if ( (visited[n4] == false) || (visited[n1] == false) || (visited[n3] == false))
            {
                int arr2[3] = {n4,n1,n3};
                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr2[rand()%3];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }

        //если находимся в последнем столбце
        if ((t%10 == 9) && (t!=9) && (t!=99))
        {
            //верхний, левый, нижний
            if ( ( visited[n2] == false) || (visited[n3] == false) || ( visited[n4]== false))
            {
                int arr3[3] = {n2,n3,n4};

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr3[rand()%3];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }

            }
        }

        //если находимся в последней строчке
        if (((t+10)>=100) && (t != 90) && (t != 99))
        {
            //верхний, левый, правый
            if ( ( visited[n1] == false) || (visited[n2] == false) || ( visited[n4] == false))
            {
                int  arr4[3] = {n1,n2, n4};

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr4[rand()%3];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }

        if (t == 0)
        {
            if ( (visited[n1] == false) || (visited[n3] == false) )
            {
                int arr5[2] = {n1, n3};

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr5[rand()%2];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }
        if (t == 9)
        {
            if ( (visited[n2] == false) || (visited[n3] == false) )
            {
                int arr6[2] = {n2, n3};

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr6[rand()%2];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }
        if (t == 90)
        {
            if ( (visited[n1] == false) || (visited[n1] == false) )
            {
                int arr7[2] = { n4, n1};

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr7[rand()%2];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }

        if (t == 99)
        {
            if ( (visited[n2] == false) || (visited[n4] == false) )
            {
                int  arr8[2] = { n4, n2};

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr8[rand()%2];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if (neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }

        if (((t-10)>=0) && ((t+10) < 100) && (t%10 != 9) && (t%10 != 0))
        {
            //рандом всех сторон
            if ( (visited[n1] == false) || (visited[n2] == false) || (visited[n3] == false) || (visited[n4] == false ))
            {
                int arr9[4] = {n1, n2, n3, n4} ;

                while (neigbour != false){
                    t = arr9[rand()%4];
                    neigbour = visited[t];
                }
                if(neigbour == false){
                    generation(t);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: не совсем видно, наверно, мою проблему, поэтому дублирую:
пишу функцию, которая должна обойти 100 элементов в одномерном массиве, представленном в виде таблице, переходить к существующему соседу(любому), а далее из нее вызываю функцию, которая будет присваивать этому соседу какое-то число( для начала  всем  5), но обходятся не все 100 элементов

Comment: вы пишете цикл, чтобы обойти 100 элементов, но в этом же цикле, присваиваете переменной для индексации какие то другие значения и ставите мешок условий (не говоря о мешке повторного кода). Лично у меня  появляется в голове только  вопрос: " Да что же вы делаете, что за чудо вы придумали?  Не лучше просто снова подумать что вы хотели делать?..."

Comment: да, понимаю, пыталась сделать так, чтобы не менялось значение t, но почему-то вообще не работало.

Comment: поэтому не значение t меняйте, а  другую переменную инициализируйте этим значением, которая зависит от значения t и используйте его. Но я так и не понял ваши намерения, поэтому дельного совета дать не могу по поводу того, как именно  и какое значение, но  ваш подход точно нужно пересмотреть.

Comment: Хорошо, пересмотрю. Вообще я пытаюсь нарисовать дерево обходом в глубину. То есть обхожу все элементы матрицы, у каждого элемента ищу соседа, которого я еще не посещала, выбираю рандомного, перехожу в функцию, которая присваивает конечному массиву  в выбранном индексе значение 5, дальше ничего еще не делала, т.к. эта часть не работает. Видимо, при проверке соседей я слишком мудрю

Comment: на похожие задачи есть много примеров, гуглите, найдете. Все намного проще делается, чем вы пытаетесь, а для рандомного выбора тоже напишите функцию, которая  возвращает один из трех  ссылок, и  вызовите функцию, вместо того, чтоб каждый раз писать один и тот же код.